# Fade out is not executed at the right time

Tags: ffmpeg

I have

```
-y -ss 00:03:23.382 -i "G:\video.MP4" -t 00:00:18.321 -af "afade=t=in:ss=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=00:00:16.321:d=2" -c:v libx264 3.mp4
```

yet the fade out is not executed. From where does `st` in `out` count here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colons in duration have to be escaped, and the whole string quoted:

```
st='00\:00\:05.729'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. For some reason the "[-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]" time format doesn't work with the fade out, at least for me..

I made it work using the "[-]S+[.m...]" format, so basically your command would like like this :

```
-y -ss 00:03:23.382 -i "G:\video.MP4" -t 00:00:18.321 -af "afade=t=in:ss=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=16.321:d=2" -c:v libx264 3.mp4
```

Comment: @Mulvya's reply made me realize that afade separates by colons (:). So without escaping them, it presumes the time to be commands.